# Async tests with Jest (without Promises)

Tags: jestjs

Is there a way to test something like this with Jest:

```js
function hello(callback) {
  someNonPromiseBasedAPI(callback);
}
```

Something like `done()`/`waitsFor()` in Jasmine

The Jest documentation states that to test an async function it must return a Promise but I don't want to modify my code to suit the test.

Answer (score 0):

Just mock out `someNonPromiseBasedAPI`

```js
jest.mock('./path/to/someNonPromiseBasedAPI', (cb)=> cb('test'))
const cb = jest.fn()
const result = hello(cb)
expect(cb).toHaveBeenCalledWith('test')
```

This replace the implementation of `someNonPromiseBasedAPI` with function that just call the callback function with `'test'`. In your test you create a spy pass it into the `hello` function. The mock is used and call the spy with `'test'`. Then just test that the spy was called wit the expected argument.

Answer (score 0):

Jest uses jasmine under the hood so you're free to use the [`done` / `done.fail`](http://jasmine.github.io/2.3/introduction.html#section-53) callback, e.g.

```js
it('says hello', done => {
    hello((err, result) => {
        if (err) return done.fail(err); 
        expect(result).toBe('hello');
        done();
    });
});
```